# Need help activation MS Project 2016 with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-project, activation

Hi I am trying to write a powershell script to auto activate MS Project 2016
I have the product key take out obviously lol so where it says product key just image there being a product key listed there.

```
$FileName = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS"
if (Test-Path $FileName) {
    #Write-Host "File Exists"
    cscript.exe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /act ProductKey
}
else
{
    Write-Host "File Doesn't Exists"
}
```

After running the powershell I get this VBS error listed below...

ERROR CODE: 462
ERRO DESCRIPTION: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Comment: 1) You are specifying the filename twice (why not reuse the variable?). 2) If the error is coming from the VBScript script, then you will need to figure that part out first.

Comment: Read the documentation around using ospp.vbs - it needs to be edited for your environment